# Best strategy for the first player in a game for two on a large checkered paper

Tags: algorithms, recreational-mathematics, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Here's a puzzle that's been seating in the back of my head for quite a long time.

> The game is played on a grid of *infinite* dimensions; sufficiently large checkered paper. First player specifies the square area of either 4 or 9 cells. He can't choose the same area twice. Second player marks an unmarked cell within this area. If he can't make his move, he loses. What is the minimal amount of turns the first player need to assuredly beat the second player?

I can't think of a good approach here other than randomly sort through various situation in attempt to beat the second player. Any tips and suggestions on how to tackle this problem, what math methods to use, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask why the seemingly arbitrary choice of $4$ or $9$? The variant with either just $4$ or just $9$ seems almost as complex.

Comment: @DanRust The first player can't win if they only have one type of square at their disposal - in that case "mark the top left corner of the square" is a winning strategy for the second player. So, having two types of squares is necessary.

Comment: @DanRust, side of the square area can either be 2 or 3. Thus 4 and 9. And  what  Milo Brandt wrote ;)

Comment: ok that makes sense.

Comment: why cant the first player just choose the same 4-cell square five times in a row?  am i missing something in the description of the rules?

Comment: @MarkFischler, yeah, that's why the first player "can't choose the same area twice"

Comment: Since the game is finite, and there's no way for the first player to lose (or are your rules missing something, like "the first player must choose a square in which there is at least one empty cell, or else the first player loses"?), an upper bound on the number of moves is $K/4$, where $K$ is the area of the initial rectangular grid (I'm ASSUMING it's rectangular...if not, a $1 \times K$ strip makes it impossible for player 1 to ever move, which I guess means that player 1 loses... anyhow, I suspect that $K/4$ is pretty close to a best upper bound as well (i.e., I agree with Xoff's answer).

Comment: @JohnHughes, I'm sorry, I misphrased an important part of the statement. The paper is sufficiently large, so we can consider it infinite. We can't rely on hitting boundaries.

Comment: Stealing Dan Rust's briefly posted idea: pick all 3x3 squares in a 6x6 square. There are 16 of these. Then pick all 2x2s in there -- another 25. The opponent must pick 16 + 25 = 41 squares out of the 36, i.e., must lose at some point. So a lower bound is 37.

Comment: In fact: start with a 6x5 block and pick all 33s: 12 of them, and all 2x2s (20 of them) to make the opponent pick 32 of the 30 squares. Hence a better lower bound is 31.

Comment: For an $n\times m$ grid, there are a total of $(n-2)(m-2)$ $3\times 3$ and $(n-1)(m-1)$ $2\times 2$ areas to choose from, giving a total of $2nm-3n-3m+5$ areas. Player 1 is guaranteed to win as long as this value is greater than $nm$.

Comment: Yeah...that's what I was getting at. :)

Comment: It's possible that player one could force a win on a slightly bigger board with fewer moves (using some clever strategy), but that would require case checking I think - probably on a computer.

Comment: Interestingly, the dimensions of the areas you can pick has little to do with it. The key point is that we can pick two types of area so that the inequality you get (as above) has a positive quadratic term, which can then always dominate the linear terms for sufficiently large $n,m$.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the first player has to choose a new grid with each turn, and the second player has to make a mark in this grid, when can either player win or lose?

Comment: @KaliMa, the grid is the same, the first player chooses different areas on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

**Upper Bound Answer**

In a $n\times n$ square area, there are $(n-m+1)^2$ square areas of size $m$ and $n^2$ squares of size $1$.

Hence
$$n^2<(n-8 )^2+(n-3 )^2$$
implies
$$0<n^2-22n+73$$
implies $n\ge 18$ (and also $n\le 4$ but its irrelevant).

So choose all possible squares of size $4$ (there are 225) and $9$ (there are 100) in a square of size $18$ that only have 324 square of size 1, and you will eventually win at move 325 (before if the other player makes mistakes).

So the minimal amout of turns is lower or equal to 325.

*I have the feeling that it can't be improved, but I don't have time now to pursue further...*

**EDIT**

for $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ cells, you obtain
$$n^2<(n-1)^2+(n-2)^2$$
$$0<n^2-6n+5$$

So $n\ge 6$ with the same strategy and you will win at turn 37.
As suggested by John Hugues, a strategy on a $6\times 5$ rectangle is enough, and you will win at turn 31. (or a $8\times 4$ rectangle also is enough and you'll win at turn 33.)

Comment: Here, you use *size* to refer to the side length, where the question specifies the area. So, you should really calculate $n^2<(n-1)^2+(n-2)^2$, which is first satisfied for $n=6$. (Though, one does better by playing all the squares in a $6\times 5$ region - and this is the smallest rectangle, by area, which does the trick. Even better is to play all the squares in a $6\times 5$ region not including the top left corner - you have $30$ moves, your opponent has $29$)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, but it seems that I poorly phrased an important part of the statement. We can't rely on hitting boundaries because the paper is unknowingly large, consider it infinite. (also to @MiloBrandt)

Comment: @Glinka The strategy suggested here is that, though the paper has no boundaries, the first player simply never plays outside of a $n\times n$ square - thus the second player can never play outside of that square either. Since the first player can make more moves than the second player strictly within that square for $n\geq 6$, they win by, at the outset of the game, deciding on a $6\times 6$ square, and always playing within it.

Comment: And in fact 6 x 5 is sufficient as well, as my comments and Dan Rust's idea/comment show.

Comment: @MiloBrandt, ok, I see. Yeah, that works